# how to use the keyboard tab to select an option in the mdbselect feild

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap, mdb-select

> I want the user to be able to use the keyboard to select options in the form that I used mdbselect, but no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

> 

```
> <MDBCol className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 text-left controlled select">
>     <MDBSelect
>      getValue={(value) => handleListChanged(value, "user")}
>      name="users"
>      options={formData.user.options}
>      required
>      color="teal"
>      selected="Select user"
>      label="user"
>      />
>   </MDBCol
> 
> >
```